# How to check if an item/element exists in array of object ( depth 4 level ) in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

I am working on an angular application where I have loaded site settings from an API, this api returns a json object something like following

```
"data":{
  "merchant_settings": {
    "admin": {
      "def_referral_amount": 50,
      "card_payment_mode": "test",
      "min_amount": 150,
      "payment_mode": true
    },
    "bookings": {
      "allow_calendar_to_customer": {
        "enable": "yes",
        "layout": "month"
      },
    },
  },
}
```

In the template file, I have section to be shown based on the data returned like if `allow_calendar_to_customer.enable == yes` then show a calendar to customer. this is working properly if I am getting data from API but sometimes it is possible that this data is not saved in db and hence it will not be returned in response. To handle this case, I have added conditions like following

```
if( typeof(data) !== 'undefined' && 
        typeof(data.merchant_settings) !== 'undefined' && 
        typeof(data.merchant_settings.bookings) !== 'undefined' && 
        typeof(data.merchant_settings.bookings.allow_calendar_to_customer) !== 'undefined' && 
typeof(data.merchant_settings.bookings.allow_calendar_to_customer.enable) !== 'undefined' && 
        data.merchant_settings.bookings.allow_calendar_to_customer.enable == yes){
              /* show required content */
}
```

In this condition, I have to check each and every parent element which I think is not a good solution but I am also not sure what is the best way to handle this case, I was expecting that something like below will work but its not.

```
if( typeof(data.merchant_settings.bookings.allow_calendar_to_customer.enable) !== 'undefined' && data.merchant_settings.bookings.allow_calendar_to_customer.enable == yes){
      /* show required content */
    }
```

can someone suggest me a better way to implement these type of conditions so that I dont have to check all the attributes in object ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Optional Chaining.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid. The ?. operator functions similarly to the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined.

---

It's been around for long enough that every non-IE browser can use it - see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining).

If you need to support those 1.4% of users that use IE, [you can use `undefined` without the `typeof` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), just `==`, which will clean up your code a bit.

Comment: yes it works typescript isn't executed anyway and a valid javascript is a valid typescript as well, it translate to équivalent older javascript (for example es5), the output of it would look like your first code

Comment: @Vikram Starting from ts3.7

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes optional chaining is one of the latest ecmascript features

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Angular version should not make a difference. Which browser are you using